# Why is there missing code in our Git repository and can it be solved with rebase?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

We work with the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow), basically a central repository that we create branches from. When we're working on bugfixes and small patches we will create a branch off of master:

```
git checkout -b master_bug123 master
```

When we're done with our commits, we do the following to merge it back in:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge master_bug123
git branch -d master_bug123
```

Sometimes we have big projects that we need to all work on. For instance, making the site responsive:

```
git checkout -b responsive master
git push -u origin responsive
```

Then other members of the team can make their own feature branches like with the master:

```
git pull
git checkout -b responsive_fixmenu responsive
```

Currently, we're working on here, then to merge the changes back in for others to use:

```
git checkout responsive
git pull
git merge responsive_fixmenu
# possibly fix conflicts, add, commit, etc
git push -u origin responsive
```

Sometimes we find that code is going missing. My initial thought is that it might be down to one of us incorrectly resolving conflicts. When investigating though, I'm a bit confused. One particular file named `core.js` was missing a large chunk of code. In the file contained a string `mb-search` which I thought I could use as part of a `git show` and `grep` to see when it appeared and was removed. Using `git log core.js` I am given a list of commits, then I use that list to do something like `git show abc1234:path/to/core.js | grep -c 'mb-search'` to output how many times it appears in the file for that commit, but what that shows me is not a simple 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, or even a 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 (which point it was deleted by mistake), but a quite random looking 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, etc.

This leads me to the first part of my questions. Am I right in saying that if another user comes along and makes changes and makes a commit (let's call it **abc1111**), *then* does a `git pull` (merging in other pushed changes) which creates a merge commit (let's call it **abc2222** - where the *mb-search* is merged in), then commit **abc1111** will *not* contain the `mb-search` code that was later merged in with **abc2222**, after it has been pushed? If so, **how can I reliably tell when some code was deleted?**

This leads me on to `rebase`. Before we were using the `responsive` branch in the same way as the `master` branch, we used to just make changes directly to `responsive`, commit and push. At the time we were using `rebase` by default. At this point we were finding we had a lot of problems, as I'm sure would be expected. As beginners using git, trying to get to grips with the basics, we decided to just use `merge` and never `rebase` and we thought we were problem free. However now I'm seeing the above problems, I', wondering if the above could be fixed (or at least helped) by using `rebase` instead, but only in specific conditions.

I think before we were rebasing on the main `responsive` repository so commits were all over the place, code missing, etc, generally what you'd expect from someone who doesn't yet grasp the rebase rules properly. However, would this be a legit use of rebase, and safe?

```
git checkout -b responsive_somefeature responsive
# write code, make commits
git pull --rebase responsive
git checkout responsive
git merge responsive_somefeature
```

Am I right in saying this would base all my new work in `responsive_somefeature` on the `HEAD` of `responsive`, so that when I merge it back in it will be linear? Is the last `merge` correct, or should/could that be a `rebase` also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I right in saying ...

Yes: merging a change creates a new commit with two (or more, but usually two) parents. It doesn't re-write either parent to include the other.

---

> If so, how can I reliably tell when some code was deleted?

Not having introduced a feature isn't the same as having deleted it. The following graph following a merge:

```
base -> abc1111 [foo]  -> {merge} abc2222 [with foo and mb-search]
     \                         /
      \-> abc0000 [mb-search] /
```

Doesn't show `abc1111` deleting *mb-search*. Looking for mb-search_ in that commit won't show it either, though. Basically, you're checking the wrong thing.

---

Instead, try `git blame --reverse base..abc2222`

> --reverse
>
> Walk history forward instead of backward. Instead of showing the revision in which a line appeared, this shows the last revision in
>   which a line has existed. This requires a range of revision like
>   START..END where the path to blame exists in START.

if you just want to see who deleted the line.

---

Oh, and your feature branch rebase workflow should probably be:

```
git checkout -b responsive_somefeature responsive
# write code, make commits

# update local branch
git checkout responsive
git pull

# rebase feature onto updated branch
git rebase responsive responsive_somefeature
## NB. this ^ will leave your feature branch checked out

# finally merge (this should be fast-forward since we just rebased)
git checkout responsive
git merge responsive_somefeature
```

where it's sensible to do the update & rebase periodically, so you're not working against a stale view of `responsive`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. By the way, when you say `base` do you mean the first time it appeared?

Comment: `base` in the example is just the common ancestor of the change you want, and the feature branch.

Comment: Thanks @Useless. Also would you mind elaborating a little on the difference between your suggested rebase workflow and what I wrote?

Comment: If you merge, you have two timelines running in parallel between the last common ancestor and the merge commit. Those timelines will be interleaved if you just look at commits-ordered-by-date, so changes on one branch will seem to appear and disappear. If you rebase instead, you get a single timeline with no mysterious interleaving.